# Java: Call and Access array by its name, which is stored in a string inside different array or variable

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have multiple arrays and depending on the users input, which is stored in a string, I need to access the corresponding array.
For example, the user types "/kit food" and presses enter, the string then gets sub-stringed to become "food".
Lets say I already have an array called food and I want to print all of the items inside of it out into the console.
here is an example code to what I'm trying to do:

```
String[] food = {"apple","carrot","pickle"};
String[] tools = {"hoe","shovel","rake"};

userInput = "food";   //already sub stringed from "/kit food"

for(String item : userInput){   //I need it to access the array food
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Would this be possible to do? or should I just manually code each if/else statement for every kit?

Comment: Java variables don't work that way.  If you need to associate strings to arrays, consider using a `Map`.

Comment: You could add the arrays to a `Map` with each array's key being its name. Then, just use `objMap.get(userInput)` to get the array the user requested.

Comment: ``Map`` interface is designed for this case, have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: Also, if the strings are pre-defined ("food", "tools", etc.) and don't change per run of the program, you might want to look into an enum-based implementation of the Command pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 7

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] food = {"apple", "carrot", "pickle"};
        String[] tools = {"hoe", "shovel", "rake"};

        String userInput = "food";   //already sub stringed from "/kit food"

        Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();    
        map.put("food", food);
        map.put("tools", tools);

        for (String item : map.get(userInput)) {   //I need it to access the array food
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, I also did some searching on YouTube regarding maps and hashmaps to understand them better. :)